# Efficiently extract a subset of rows from a large DataTable?

Tags: .net, datatable, performance

Given the following table, as an example:

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| ID | GroupID | OtherData |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 1  | 1       | w4ij6u    |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 2  | 2       | ai6465    |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 3  | 2       | ows64rg   |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 4  | 2       | wqoi46suj |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 5  | 3       | w9rthzv   |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 6  | 3       | 03ehsat   |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 7  | 4       | w469ia    |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 8  | 5       | nhwh57rt  |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 9  | 5       | mwitgjhx4 |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

How can I efficiently get a `List<List<DataRow>>` extracted from this table that is based upon the "GroupID" column?

Basically, I want the result to be:

```
MyList(0) = List: 1 DataRow, ID(s) 1
MyList(1) = List: 3 DataRows, ID(s) 2,3,4
MyList(2) = List: 2 DataRows, ID(s) 5,6
MyList(3) = List: 1 DataRow, ID(s) 7
MyList(4) = List: 2 DataRows, ID(s) 8,9
```

Here's the problem though: **This DataTable contains hundreds of columns and tens of thousands of rows, so this operation must be as efficient as possible.**

I have already tried the following methods:

- Creating a `DataView` with a Row Filter, and extracting a table/list of rows from that view.
- A Linq query within a loop, after getting a unique list of GroupIDs. The Linq query selects each "set" of GroupIDs based on a `Where` clause.

I'm hoping someone else has a better, more efficient way of extracting this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that A) My returning data set was too large (because of a bug), and B) LINQ is probably the fastest way to do this, without writing some very long or hack-ish code. Thanks for your ideas, everyone, but I'll stick with LINQ for now.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the DataTable.Select() method? Here's an example of how to use it:

```
DataTable table = GetSomeData();
DataRow[] results = table.Select("SomeInt > 0");

List<DataRow> resultList = results.ToList();
```

Using DataTable.Select should definitely be quicker than DefaultView.Filter, and as you can see the ability to put the results in a list is already built in.

Comment: Using `.Select()` is the same as performing a LINQ query on the table, it's just written differently (the underlying code is almost the same, though). This is, so far, the fastest method, but still takes a pretty long time.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you have to filter the results a this level. Wouldn't it be faster to do it at the database level?

Comment: How is that possible, though? The database cannot return a variable number of tables. (Variable, meaning, changes at runtime.)

Comment: What do you mean? Why can't you write a stored procedure that pulls all of the information that you need, and execute that stored procedure at runtime? Do you have a list of results that you need, based on a user selection or something? Can you elaborate on why this approach is necessary?

Comment: I guess, ultimately, I want to be able to split my results into groups based on a column. Using the example above, basically, I want separate tables with a maximum of two "`GroupID`'s" each (including all of the other columns). I thought my question was detailed enough that I didn't have to explain that, but I guess not. Ultimately, I need all the data in the results, I just need it chopped up.